# compilation issues with pdflatex on msys2

Tags: compiling, paths, cygwin

I installed both texlive and miktex as well as cygwin and msys on a new machine. Now, after adding the paths to the pdflatex.exe in either texlive or miktex installation folders I can compile my tex files via cygwin without problems. However, via MSYS2 MINGW-64 the executable is not found. Can someone tell me how I can achieve that?

Comment: you just need to set the path but it's not clear what you installed.  presumably(?) native windows miktex and cygwin (not windows) texlive? On msys2 you'd presumably(?) want a native windows tex so you plan to use miktex there?

Comment: I'm running windows. basically I'm happy with cygwin, since I can compile tex code without problems with either miktex or texlive (I'll probably uninstall texlive, since I really like the on the fly package installation feature of miktek). as for msys2, I just wanted to see if I could compile tex code with it as easily as I can with cygwin. I can compile c code with msys2, but for some reason, I cannot do the same with tex code. I already added msys2 ... bin to the path, but it didn't really help

Comment: I always use cygwin texlive in cygwin. Using native windows binaries is possible but tricky as they do not understand the virtual cygwin file system paths or symbolic links etc.  on the fly packge installation is not so much of an issue as with modern disks you can easily install a full texlive (I have several: 2020, 2021, 2022) but in an msys2 shell it should work if you set the PATH to include the miktex bin directory I would have expected

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot for the feedback David! I'll keep trying out alternative paths and let you know, if I made some kind of progress

Comment: no success. from what I could find out I need to install texlive directly from the msys2 shell using pacman. what's not clear is which exact packages I should install. in theory, if I preinstall texlive, I just need to install the bin package from the msys2 shell. does that make sense to you?

Comment: I can't see any reason why you would not be able to use a windows texlive with msys, what did you set PATH to, and what error did you get? Conversly with cygwin you should use a cygwin texlive, either the one in the cygwin default, or from TUG

Comment: I have: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\bin\x64. I uninstalled texlive, but before I had a similar path for texlive and couldn't compile with msys2 shell either. error: pdflatex: command not found

Comment: you should set your PATH environment variable presumably something like `export PATH=/Program\ Files/MiKTeX\ 2.9/bin/x64:$PATH` then run pdflatex but I have neither miktex nor msys on this machine

Comment: problem solved. I followed the suggestion in section 3.1 of "Building gretel on MS Windows" and added the line `export PATH=$PATH:/C/"Program Files"/"MiKTeX 2.9"/miktex/bin/x64` to the bash_profile file in the home/user directory of MSYS2. restarted the shell and I can now compile. tex code with the pdflatex command. Appreciate the feedback David!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should set your PATH environment variable presumably something like export `PATH=/Program\ Files/MiKTeX\ 2.9/bin/x64:$PATH` then run `pdflatex`